# How to get data from the block function?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, ios8, wkwebview

I trigger a js from a WKWebView and get the result in the block function. In the block function, I got the correct data. However, when I assign this data to the external variable outside, I always get nil value.

```
- (id)triggerJS:(NSString*)js
{
    NSLog(@"JS = %@",js);

    __block id resultJS = nil;
    [self.webView evaluateJavaScript:js completionHandler: ^(id data, NSError* err) {

                                                            resultJS = [data copy];
                                                        }
     ];

    if (resultJS != nil)
    {
        NSString* str = (NSString*)resultJS;
        NSLog(@"Result of JS = %@", str);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Result of JS = nil");
    }

    return resultJS;
}
```

Why is that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the function `evaluateJavaScript` is executed asynchronous way, so when you execute the  `if (resultJS != nil)` the "`completionHandler`" is not executed yet, thats the reason that you always get `nil` value.

The best improvement for this, is trying to re-write and adapt your code inside the "`completionHandler`" block, that will manage the resultJS data.

Comment: There is no way to get the result from that function? Anyway, thanks.

Comment: No, In the way that you are trying to do. But you can call a  function or send a notification when the completionHandler block is ending.